# Impossible to use rsync with Cygwin

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, rsync

Hi I have installe cygwin and I would like to use rsync but I have this error

```
Bad owner or permissions on /home/LUPI/.ssh/config
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at 
/home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I have create the key with this command line and the key

```
       ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C "userName"
```

and the key are similar in the server and in my computer. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This question should be on superuser or serverfault, and secondly this is an ssh permissions issue and NOT a rsync issue, but here is the solution:

```
chown -R $USER:users ~/.ssh/
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/
```